# Can we get these lists in new line using return function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, return

I am new to Python, so this question may seem silly.

I want to print(using return function) each list in a new line along with if a statement is true add a string to one of the item in list :

```
row1=[1,2,3]
row2=[4,5,6]
row3=[7,8,9]

def return_func():
    a=1
    if a==1:
      return row1[0]+'b',row1[1],row1[2]
      return row2
      return row3
```

This isn't working, if there is any efficient way of this , you can post here. Thank you

Comment: `One of the item` to which list do you want to add? Will it always be row1?

Comment: `return` is not for printing. You need to use `print` to print. `return` will always end the function execution *and return control to the caller*. Also, terminology note, `return` is not a function. It is a statement

Comment: Okay, I don't know thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of problems you have with this code.

First of all, you can only return at one point during a function, after that the function is ended.

If you want to return multiple lists you have to:

```
def return_lists():
    return [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]

lst_1, lst_2, lst_3 = return_lsts()
```

If you want to print things, you have to use the `print()` command, not `return`. `return` finishes the function and sends the result back to where it was called.

Secondly, you cannot add an integer and a string, if you want to add a string to the first index of a list, you should do something like this:

```
lst_1 = [1, 2, 3]
lst_1[0] = str(lst_1[0]) + 'b'
```

Lastly, you shouldn't use global variables. You should send the lists along when calling the function:

```
def return_lists(lst_1, lst_2, lst_3):
    return lst_1, lst_2, lst_3

lst_1, lst_2, lst_3 = return_lists([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
```

Putting everything together:

```
def return_func(row1, row2, row3):
    a=1
    if a==1:
      row1[0] = str(row1[0]) + 'b'
    return row1, row2, row3

row1=[1,2,3]
row2=[4,5,6]
row3=[7,8,9]

row1_new, row2_new, row3_new = return_func(row1, row2, row3)
print(row1_new)
print(row2_new)
print(row3_new)
```

Comment: No, I want them in new line, not in the same one

Comment: @AshPro-grammar that doesn't make any sense. What doy ou mean "in new line"? What line are you talking about?

Comment: @AshPro-grammar You can get them in new line. But not with `return`. Any specific reason why you wanna do it with `return`?

Comment: I mean, I need each list in a new line (output)

Comment: @DineshKumar , I am preparing Tic Tac Toe board , So I need return function and need the lists each in a new line , so it looks like a board.

Comment: @AshPro-grammar what you are saying makes no sense. When you return a list, **there are no lines**. You are talkin about how you print some output. This has *nothing* to do with return.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , Thank you, Don't mind these silly questions, I am a beginner. :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I got my result. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like this:

```
row1=[1,2,3]
row2=[4,5,6]
row3=[7,8,9]

def return_func(row):
    a = 1
    if a == 1:
        row.insert(0, "b")
        return row
        
for row in [row1, row2, row3]:
    print(return_func(row))
```

This way you call the return_func three times, each time with each of the rows `[row1, row2, row3]`, as you can see in for loop `for row in [row1, row2, row3]:`.
Now you only need to print its return and it will print the three rows, in this case, always adding a 'b' at position 0 of all rows as in all cases the if condition is met.
Output:

```
['b', 1, 2, 3]
['b', 4, 5, 6]
['b', 7, 8, 9]
```